# C# WebAPI function is working OK on Localhost but not on IIS 10

Tags: c#, .net, iis, webapi

Good day everyone,

I try to explain my problem in simple way:
I have created a WebAPI project in C#. This project has two functions.

1. CreatePDFFromHTML (takes html string as input and convert to pdf file).
2. ConvertFileToPDF (takes path of a file, convert it to pdf and save in the same folder).
   I have created a class library project in C#. This project exposes both functions of WebAPI project.
   **Problem:**
   When I run WebAPI project in Localhost, and call both the methods in class library project it works fine but, when I deploy WebAPI project on IIS 10 (Windows server 2019) ConvertFileToPDF does not work. No Exception occurs which I can trace and share. It seems to be some user's access rights. Can some one please help me. I have already spend two days on this issue.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which others can use to re-create the issue that you're facing.

Comment: If it doesn't work but there is no exception, what happens? What is the response code from the HTTP request? There has to be something. Can you add some logging to the controller method? Are you sure your call is getting routed to the controller? Also, check Event Viewer on the server. IIS will log exceptions when they occur even if they aren't visible through the application.

Comment: it looks like path problem, you can still debug your code on server, remootly too

Comment: "I have created a class library project in C#" is far from enough. Unless you wrote every PDF conversion bits yourself and make sure it works for IIS, it usually won't work (if your code wraps over some third party PDF conversion libraries or utilities).

Comment: What I can think of permission is application pool, you need to make sure application pool have read or write permission to folder and files. But it is better to provide a  minimal reproducible sample for other members to test.

Comment: ConvertFileToPDF (takes path of a file, convert it to pdf and save in the same folder). This path is always pointing to a file on the network folder.

Comment: normaly there are permissions on network folders. Has the user, configured in the application pool of the webapp, permissions to write there ?

Comment: If the folder is a network folder, you need to set the application pool identity to account which can login the network folder server and have read write permission to folder.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I just restart and update server and it is working fine.